# weblogic 12.1.3 ,deployement exception,cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, atg

I have a ATG application on version 10.2,I am trying to deploy the appplication on weblogic 12.1.3 and facing this exception while server startup
Here is the logs snippet:

```
<Dec 22, 2017 3:51:04 PM IST> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149231> <Unable to set the activation state to true for the application "vsi_store".
 weblogic.management.DeploymentException: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.throwAppException(BaseDeployment.java:123) at weblog

    ic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:260)
    at 
    weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
    at 
    weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:16)
    at 
    weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
        Caused By: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
                at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
        2)
                at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.defineClass(GenericCla
        ssLoader.java:412)
                at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(Generic
        ClassLoader.java:366)
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue was happening because of  inbuild guava classes in 12.1.3 version of weblogic.They were interfaring with my application guava classes
I solved it by using version 12.1.2.
or you can solve it in 12.1.3 by changing entries of weblogic-application.xml as below:

```
<wls:prefer-application-packages>
    <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.github.fge.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.joda.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.google.common.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>com.sun.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.jersey.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.glassfish.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>org.jvnet.hk2.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>com.sun.research.ws.wadl.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.sun.ws.rs.ext.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
    <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>org.codehaus.jettison.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>javax.ws.rs.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</wls:package-name>

    <wls:package-name>antlr.*</wls:package-name>

    </wls:prefer-application-packages>


</wls:weblogic-application>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is the only solution which worked for me.